# Misplaced construct

Tags: java

I'm getting several *"misplaced construct"* errors and *"delete token"* errors. The description for these errors on the Oracle site are pretty vague. I can't figure out what the issue is, but it seems like I have one parenthesis out of place throwing the whole program off. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class divisorCalc2 {
    import java.util.Scanner; //Imports scanner class

    public static int gcd(int num1, int num2) {
        if (num2 == 0) {
            return num1;
        } else {    
            return gcd(num2, num1 % num2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter first integer:");
        int firstInt = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter second integer:");
        int secondInt = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println(gcd(firstInt,secondInt));

        in.close(); //Closes Scanner
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't define methods within methods unless you have a inner class

Comment: imports can't be defined in a class. put package first, then list imports, then define class below that. voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Um, now `in` is undefined, and you don't use `Scanner` anywhere after importing it. Are those two facts related somehow?

Comment: As @NathanHughes suggests, correct your question.

Comment: BTW, the answers don't make any sense if you keep changing the code in the question. If you want to incorporate suggested changes and get another look, please put the new code below the old code so we can see the original _and_ the updated. You're actually defacing your question as we go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a method inside another. Take the whole gcd code outside of main.

```
main (...){
  ...
}

gcd (...){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Mind that OP changed his question about this part.

Answer (score 0):

You have a method inside another, move it outside main method, you don't have a scanner declared too, you imported the scanner class but is not defined yet.

Here:

```
   public static int gcd(int num1, int num2) {
        if (num2 == 0) {
            return num1;
        } else {
            return gcd(num2, num1 % num2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter first integer:");
        int firstInt = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter second integer:");
        int secondInt = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(gcd(firstInt, secondInt));

        input.close(); //Closes Scanner
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a class definition, package declaration is first line, any import(s) is second line. Next comes the 'public class ...'. Your program fails here itself. Take imports statement above, immediate after package.